# multiple the value when only 1 checkbox is selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a checkbox where each list of item has different amount.. But only 1 checkbox is based on per hour calculation.. All other checkbox are not based on per hour calculation. When user selects that perticular checkbox the amount has get calculated based on so much hours.. For eg if the hour selected is 4.when the checkbox for video is selected the the amount textbox the value has to be 4*1000= 4000
How can I calculate the value

Here is the code

```html
<input type="text" value="3" name="t1">
<label>Book Slots for</label><br/>
<div id="catlist1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="audio" value="Audio Recording" data-price="600">
  Audio Recording

  <input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="video" value="Video Recording" required data-price="1000"> <b>  Video Recording </b>
  </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="editing" value="Audio editing/dubbing" required data-price="600"> <b>  Audio editing/dubbing </b>
  </label><br/>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="video_editing" value="Video Editing" required data-price="1000"> <b> Video Editing: 1000 per hour </b>
  </label><br/>
```

Here when user checks on video editing the value has to value of textbox1 and checkbox video editing i.e 1000

Here is the code for calculating total

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcAndShowTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#catlist1 :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price')) || 0;

    });
    $('#total').val(total);
  }
  $('#catlist1 :checkbox').change(calcAndShowTotal).change();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to only one checkbox to be checked?

Comment: No.. Multiple can be selected.. But only when video editing checkbox is selected the value has to calculated has t1*1000(For eg 4*1000)

Comment: Suppose all are selected,since it includes video editing,so all of them needs to be calcuate like `t1*1000`?

Comment: I want to multiple the total of data-pph value which is true and hoursselected is 4 only when the user selects video editing checkbox the value has to hoursselected*1000. + if the user selects any other checkbox say video recording the value is 600 the it has to be hoursselected*1000+ 600= 3600

Comment: Then you can check Quatban Taco's answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a unique identifier for the checkbox that requires a calculation of price per hour.
An example would be to give the checkboxes another data attribute.

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="audio" value="Audio Recording" data-pph="false" data-price="600">
<b>Audio Recording</b>
</label>
<br/>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="video" value="Video Recording" data-pph="false" data-price="1000"> 
<b> Video Recording </b>
</label>
<br />

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="editing" value="Audio editing/dubbing" data-pph="false" data-price="600"> <b> Audio editing/dubbing </b>
</label>
<br />

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sponsor[]" id="video_editing" value="Video Editing" data-pph="true" data-price="1000"> <b> Video Editing: 1000 per hour </b>
</label>
<br/>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcAndShowTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    var hoursSelected = $('#hoursSelected').val();
    $('#catlist1 input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('data-pph')) {
        total += hoursSelected * parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price')) || 0;
      } else {
        total += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price')) || 0;
      }
    });
    $('#total').val(total);
  }
  $('#catlist1 :checkbox').change(calcAndShowTotal).change();
</script>
```

PS: You need to smoothen your HTML and question writing skills. :)

Comment: This would be better as a runnable snippet.

Comment: You still need to create an inputbox for the hoursSelected if you haven't created one already. Or change the  $('#hoursSelected').val() part to the id of your hours selected checkbox.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, OP only provided partial code and i modified according to my understanding of the question. Like i said, he could have done a little better with the question. :)

Comment: I want to multiple the total of data-pph value which is true and hoursselected is 4 only when the user selects video editing checkbox the value has to hoursselected*1000. + if the user selects any other checkbox say video recording the value is 600 the it has to be hoursselected*1000+ 600= 3600

Comment: Here for each checkbox selected it is getting multiplies